# Delphi Error: Got "untyped", expected "AnsiString"

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, pascal, var, lazarus

Below is a sample from a file preview system project that I am working on. There are two ListBoxes on the main form. The first one, [lst_fileList], displays a list of all ".txt" files in a directory [files], each labeled [order###.txt], with the ### being any number from 1 to 999. When the procedure is run, it finds the selected item in the listbox, (a .txt file), and then displays each individual line from within the file upon the second ListBox [lst_filePreview].

Although as I run it, an error occurs on the 21st line at the ReadLn(selectedFile). The error states (Incompatible Type: Got "untyped", expected "AnsiString").

I have looked into this error for a few hours now, to no avail... Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

---

```
procedure TForm1.btn_getPreviewClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  checkSelect:integer;
  orderSelect:string;
  i:integer;
  selectedFile:textFile;
begin
  if lst_fileList.SelCount > 0 then
  begin
    for checkSelect:= 0 to (lst_fileList.Items.Count - 1) do
    if lst_fileList.Selected [checkSelect] then
    begin
      orderSelect:=lst_fileList.Items[checkSelect];
      orderSelect:=RightStr(orderSelect,3);
      if fileexists('files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt') then
      begin
        assignFile(selectedFile,'files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt');
        reset(selectedFile);
        while not EOF(selectedFile) do
        begin
          lst_filePreview.Items.Add(readLn(selectedFile));    // Error occurs here: //
        end;
        closeFile(selectedFile);
      end;
    end;
  end else
  ShowMessage('Please select an item first!');
end;
```

Comment: In the question I see, it is declared as "textFile".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code

```
  lst_filePreview.Items.Add(readLn(selectedFile));
```

tries to use Readln as a function. It is not. It is, officially, a procedure, which is like a function returning void (untyped). In reality, it is a compiler-magic procedure, and depending on what it actually tries to read, the compiler inserts calls to different runtime functions or procedures.

You may want to get rid of the old Pascal-style routines altogether, and use streams instead, but for now, try:

```
  s: string

  ...

  Readln(selectedFile, s);
  lst_filePreview.Items.Add(s);
```

Please read the Delphi DocWiki notes at [Standard Routines and Input-Output](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Standard_Routines_and_Input-Output), saying:

> Note: For new programs, you might want to use the File Management
>   classes and functions in the System.Classes and System.SysUtils units.
>   System.Classes.TStream and its descendent classes are currently
>   recommended for general file handling in Delphi (for related routines,
>   see Streams, Reader and Writers). For text-file handling,
>   TStreamReader and TStreamWriter are recommended over calling Write and
>   Writeln. API Categories Index contains lists of related routines and
>   classes.

And if your `lst_filePreview` is in fact a `TListBox`, you can even do:

```
lst_filePreview.Items.LoadFromFile('files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt');
```

and save yourself the entire reading code. I would probably use a `TMemo` instead and do:

```
FilePreviewMemo.Lines.LoadFromFile('files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt');
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. Thank you very much.
I knew I was missing some small detail...

Comment: Take a look at my edit: use LoadFromFile and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 2):

Using Readln, you need to use a variable.

Try this:

```
var
 checkSelect:integer;
 orderSelect:string;
 i:integer;
 selectedFile:textFile;
 SelectedLine : String;
begin
  if lst_fileList.SelCount > 0 then
  begin
    for checkSelect:= 0 to (lst_fileList.Items.Count - 1) do
    if lst_fileList.Selected [checkSelect] then
    begin
       orderSelect:=lst_fileList.Items[checkSelect];
       orderSelect:=RightStr(orderSelect,3);
       if fileexists('files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt') then
       begin
          assignFile(selectedFile,'files\order'+orderSelect+'.txt');
          reset(selectedFile);
          while not EOF(selectedFile) do
          begin
            readLn(selectedFile, SelectedLine )
            lst_filePreview.Items.Add( SelectedLine);// Error occurs here:         
          end;
         closeFile(selectedFile);
         end;
         end;
       end else
       ShowMessage('Please select an item first!');
       end;
```